# Apache Drill | Get table list from REST API

Tags: apache-drill

Any one can explain how to get table list via Drill REST API.
I have tried with `show database` -> `use mysql.db` -> `show table list`
Able to get DB list but not able to get table list from respective DB.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT FROM COMMENT**

My JSON request like this first :

```
{ "queryType" : "SQL", "query" : "USE MYSQL.dbtest" }
```

I got default schema result, then I sent

```
{ "queryType" : "SQL", "query" : "SHOW TABLES" }
```

then i got exception like this

```
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: No default schema selected. Select a schema using 'USE schema' command [Error Id: e4e2d2f4-6f08-4ef9-9be3-ba3bbe2d20d9 on spark-slave:31010]
```

Comment: My JSON request like this first : { "queryType" : "SQL", "query" : "USE MYSQL.dbtest" } i got default schema result ,then i sent { "queryType" : "SQL", "query" : "SHOW TABLES" } then i got exception like this org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: No default schema selected. Select a schema using 'USE schema' command [Error Id: e4e2d2f4-6f08-4ef9-9be3-ba3bbe2d20d9 on spark-slave:31010]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and refrain from using comments for new information.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to help with little information. Since you provided no information about your JSON request strings I have to assume.

First, https://drill.apache.org/docs/rest-api/#query shows that you can send a query to Drill. This might be what you have used.

Secondly, there is no command `show table list`. Even directly in Drill, this shouldn't work. The correct command, also to be found in the documentation under https://drill.apache.org/docs/show-tables/ is `SHOW TABLES;`

If you need any further help, please add more information.

**EDIT**

It seems that Drill is not "remembering" your `USE` command. Maybe a new session is being opened. To avoid needing to use `USE`, you could try including the database identifier in your `SHOW` statement.

```
{ "queryType" : "SQL", "query" : "SHOW MYSQL.dbtest.TABLES" }
```

I am not sure if that is possible, though. What should work is using the `SELECT` statement:

```
{ "queryType" : "SQL", "query" : "SELECT * FROM MYSQL.dbtest.<a_table_name>" }
```

Comment: Thanks for response. my JSON request like this                                    first :                                                                                                           {
      "queryType" : "SQL",
      "query" : "USE MYSQL.dbtest"
}